# java weird increment syntax

Tags: java, syntax, increment

So I have always been taught that in Java, using the increment operator after a variable name in an expression will do the expression, and then increment the value and using the operator before a variable name in an expression will do the increment before the evaluation.  Like this:

```
int x = 0;
int y = x++;
```

after this executes y should be 0 and x should be 1.  and in this example

```
int x = 0;
int y = ++x;
```

should be x = 1 and y = 1.

Following that same logic, the following...

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
x = y++ - y++;
```

should output 0 as x and 2 as y because 0 - 0 = 0.
However the output is

```
x = -1
y = 2
```

Why is this?

Edit:  the value of y does not matter.  x will always equal -1 and y will (in the end) equal y + 2.

Comment: `0` - `1` = `-1`  Set a breakpoint and do it step by step.

Comment: I apologize for this question...  But I was taught that when there was a variable++ it always happened after the statement was done.  I need to ask my teacher about that :(

Comment: Well, it happens after the statement is evaluated. And logic like this is evaluated left to right. For example the second condition in an `&&` doesn't execute if the first is false. It's still a little surprising.

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
x = y++ - y++;
x = (0) - (1)
y = 1 ---> 2 // after ++
```

So `x = -1` and `y = 2`

Comment: but the variable++ is always supposed to happen AFTER the statement.

Comment: @JohnDoe `y++` the value of `y` is returned (0), and then the `++` occurs increment `y`. The next `y++`, the value of `y` is returned, it is now `1`, and `++` increments `y`, going to `2`.

Comment: After the statement (the increment), not after the whole line. You have two increments on one line, and the result of the first *is* visible to the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = y++ - y++;
```

equals

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
a = y++; // 0
b = y++; // 1
c = y;
-1 = a - b;
2 = y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you assumptions are incorrect. In your first case

```
int x = 0;
int y = x++;
```

x is 0 and y is 1 because y takes the incremented value of x. Similarly for your second case x is 0 and y is 1.
For your final case:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
x = y++(y is 1 here) - y++(y is 2 now);
```

so here y++, makes y 1 then you subtract this 1 with another increment of y than makes y 2 at that point so x = 1-2= -1

Comment: thats why i say looks like. did you see that? i know the second case y =1 is correct

Comment: With that typo, it looked like you were calling us assumptions. You couldn't have meant anything by it, I guess. Too late to un-reprimand.

Comment: so you think its not rude to vote down an answer just because you did not read clearly?

Comment: We already established that the answer is not clear, which is reason enough to downvote. Why should I have to repeatedly explain myself? It's your own pride that is in question here, and a downvote is a tiny gesture.

Comment: i dont think thats enough to downvote. if you are not clear you ask more question to get clear. you dont downvote others effort to help

Comment: This community is rather generous with its downvotes, and that's not the entirety of rude attitudes I've seen. It's a lot of work explaining things that should be obvious with a little circumspection. You didn't get the hint about the tone of "all your assumptions are incorrect". I clicked to unvote after it was locked in, but you know what? Votes can change after an edit. So if it's important...

Answer (score 0):

> I was taught that when there was a variable++ it always happened after the statement was done.

Not after the *statement*, but rather after the *expression*.

Any time you have `n - (n + 1)` you get the result `-1`. The right-hand side of an assignment must be fully evaluated before the assignment can take place.